# AWK to join next row without removing it

Tags: awk

I'm using the following command to join the next row in a csv but would like do it without removing the rows.

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s, ",$0;next;}1' test.csv
```

Test.csv

```
rabbit
cat
dog
turtle
sheep
cow
```

Result:

```
rabbit, cat
dog, turtle
sheep, cow
```

Desired result:

```
rabbit, cat
cat, dog
dog, turtle
turtle, sheep
sheep, cow
cow, rabbit
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=', ' 'NR==1{first=$0} NR>1{print prev, $0} {prev=$0} END{print prev, first}' file
rabbit, cat
cat, dog
dog, turtle
turtle, sheep
sheep, cow
cow, rabbit
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way to do this in GNU `awk`, could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=', ' '
{
  for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){
    print $i,$(i+1)
  }
}
END{
  print $NF,$1
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation here.

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS=', ' '       ##Starting awk program and setting RS as NULL here and setting OFS as comma with space here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++){      ##Starting for loop from here till 2nd last field.
    print $i,$(i+1)            ##Printing current field and next field here.
  }
}
END{                           ##Starting END block of this code here.
  print $NF,$1                 ##Printing last field and first field as per OP question here.
}
' Input_file                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```